# Can I install VB6 over VS 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have already using Visual Studio 2010 for my project. Now I have to work with a Visual Basic 2006 legacy application. Can I install VB 2006 Enterprise Edition on my system?
Will this affect Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: There is no such thing as Visual Basic 2006. Do you mean Visual Studio 2005, or Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: Sorry..Can I install Visual Stdio 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple versions of Visual Studio on the same machine. I currently have VS2003, VS2005, VS2008 and VS2010 installed and am using all of them.

Where you may get into problems is with something like hooking up the older ones to TFS. This can be done, as I have VS2003 and VS2008 connected to TFS2010, but my VS2005 won't work as it whinges about the provider for some reason.

Another area to watch out for is IIS. As you have already installed VS2010, IIS may be defaulting to .Net 4.0 so if you start deploying .Net 2.0 apps then the websites may not work without some adjustment of things like app pools.

But if you are just using them independently of each other then you should be fine. If you're really paranoid, consider creating a VM and installing the old VS on it.

EDIT

I see from your edited post that you were talking about VB6. This also can be installed alongside any of the later versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 6 will happily install side-by-side.